# Why can't jQuery 3 identify the '#' character in an attribute selector?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, jquery-selectors

I just tried switching my application to jQuery 3. I was going through some testing and everything was working as expected, until I came to a piece of my application that used a '#' symbol in a selector. I have a piece of jQuery that looks like this:

```
var $existingFilter = $container.find('.filterFeedItem[data-component-type=#somefilter]');
```

Using jQuery 3 I get an error:

```
jquery-3.0.0.js:1529 Uncaught Error: Syntax error, 
unrecognized expression: .filterFeedItem[data-component-type=#somefilter]
```

Does anyone know why jQuery can no longer parse selectors containing this symbol?

Comment: Try wrapping `#somefilter` with quotes

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Note, the change apparently took place at version 2.0, as version 2.1.3 returned element using selector

```
var $existingFilter1 = $container.find('.filterFeedItem[data-component-type=#somefilter]');
```

jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/f8nej922/2/

Though have not been able to locate specific reference to or description of change at [jQuery 2.2 and 1.12 Released](https://blog.jquery.com/2016/01/08/jquery-2-2-and-1-12-released/) documentation.

As [noted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38415960/why-cant-jquery-3-identify-the-character-in-an-attribute-selector/38416027?noredirect=1#comment71125444_38416027) by @BoltClock, change is related to [Selector: Remove "#" exception for identifier tokens](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/commit/86e62d8b37ff9ad40e7c21c2c0c440a9cdfc550e).

---

You can esacape `#` character with `\\`; quote value at attribute selector; or use [`$.escapeSelector()`](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/issues/1761)

```
var $existingFilter = $container
                      .find('.filterFeedItem[data-component-type=\\#somefilter]');
```

---

```
var $existingFilter = $container
                      .find('.filterFeedItem[data-component-type="#somefilter"]');
```

---

```
var $existingFilter = $container
                      .find('.filterFeedItem[data-component-type=' 
                       + $.escapeSelector('#somefilter') + ']');
```

jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/f8nej922/4/

Comment: I marked this as correct - solid answer and thanks for the fiddle. Hadn't actually used $.escapeSelector before. I ended up opting for a solution that didn't require the '#' symbol. It's probably poor practice in general  - I was just filtering by hashtags so it sort of made sense for the situation. Thanks!

Comment: "Not certain if change is related to Selector: Remove '#' exception for identifier tokens?" Sure it is - it's linked to in the release notes. But the fix itself is in [Sizzle's codebase](https://github.com/jquery/sizzle/commit/f204a6112216f31685717d9fc1bf6cabf42b2ef1) - the release notes link to the changeset in jQuery's main repo which contains the test suite, not Sizzle itself.

Comment: @BoltClock Suggested edit? Or edit Answer to reflect correct route to noted documentation and code changes.

Comment: @Robert: The use of $.escapeSelector here is incorrect - you end up escaping the *entire* selector string and not just the attribute value. You generally only use $.escapeSelector when you do not know the attribute value in advance, e.g. if it's coming from user input.

Comment: @BoltClock What is incorrect about use of `$.escapeSelector()`? Do you suggest concatenating `$.escapeSelector()` only at attribute portion of selector?

Comment: @guest271314: `$.escapeSelector('.filterFeedItem[data-component-type=#somefilter]')` escapes the entire thing, resulting in `\.filterFeedItem\[data-component-type\=\#somefilter\]`. You're supposed to use it only to escape the attribute value. So yes, you would need to concat.

Comment: Continuing my previous comment, "So yes, you would need to concat - in which case, you might as well just quote the attribute value at the selector portion and be done with it."

Comment: @BoltClock Yes, included three possible options at Answer which should return same result.

Answer (score 3):

By [jQuery's documentation](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/), the attribute value:

> Can be either a valid identifier or a quoted string.

The valid identifier being any valid css identifier:

> https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#value-def-identifier
>
> In CSS, identifiers (including element names, classes, and IDs in
>   selectors) **can contain only the characters [a-zA-Z0-9] and ISO 10646**
>   **characters U+00A0 and higher, plus the hyphen (-) and the underscore**
>   **(_)**; they cannot start with a digit, two hyphens, or a hyphen followed
>   by a digit. Identifiers can also contain escaped characters and any
>   ISO 10646 character as a numeric code (see next item). For instance,
>   the identifier "B&W?" may be written as "B\&W\?" or "B\26 W\3F".

Since you are wanting to use `#`, you need to escape or quote the value:

```
                         //Note the quotes v --------- v
.find('.filterFeedItem[data-component-type="#somefilter"]');
```

Comment: Solid answer Patrick, I gave it to guest271314 because of the fiddle. Thanks!

Comment: This doesn't explain why jQuery treated the selector as valid for the past 10 years.