# jQuery selector for multiple select2 element using 'name' attribute tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-select2

Im attempting to output validation errors on various input and select elements on my form. But I cant seem to get the element using a class/attribute selector.
Im using form-contorl class from bootstrap to identify all the inputs and select2 plugin to fix the select boxes.

This works fine with standard input and select boxes, but with a multple select box, which requires '[]' at the end of the name attribute, it fails and returns an empty jquery object.

EDIT: Btw the `eKey` returns `genres` without the `[]`.

**HTML**

```
<select id="genre-select" class="form-control select2-hidden-accessible" multiple="" name="genres[]" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true">
    <option value="1">RPG</option>
    <option value="2">FPS</option>
    <option value="3">MMO</option>
</select>
```

**JS**

```
$.each(errors, function (eKey, messages){

    var $input = $('.form-control[name=' + eKey + ']');
    //do stuff with error messages (bootstrap popovers)
});
```

Any ideas how I can select the input element via a jquery selector?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use attribute begins with selector

```js
var eKey = "genres";
var $input = $('.form-control[name^=' + eKey + ']');
console.log($input[0].name);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="genre-select" class="form-control select2-hidden-accessible" multiple="" name="genres[]" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true">
    <option value="1">RPG</option>
    <option value="2">FPS</option>
    <option value="3">MMO</option>
</select>
```

or escape selector string

```js
var eKey = "genres\\[\\]";
var $input = $('.form-control[name=' + eKey + ']');
console.log($input[0].name);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="genre-select" class="form-control select2-hidden-accessible" multiple="" name="genres[]" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true">
    <option value="1">RPG</option>
    <option value="2">FPS</option>
    <option value="3">MMO</option>
</select>
```

at jQuery version 3+

```js
var eKey = $.escapeSelector("genres[]");
var $input = $('.form-control[name=' + eKey + ']');
console.log($input[0].name);
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.0.0.js"></script>
<select id="genre-select" class="form-control select2-hidden-accessible" multiple="" name="genres[]" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true">
    <option value="1">RPG</option>
    <option value="2">FPS</option>
    <option value="3">MMO</option>
</select>
```

See also [Why can't jQuery 3 identify the '#' character in an attribute selector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38415960/why-cant-jquery-3-identify-the-character-in-a-selector/)

Comment: Wow prompt reply, many options, thank you. I havn't tried any of these options before. The begins selector seems the best solution, because it would be awkward to modify the 'eKey' for each check.

Answer (score 0):

You can try use different search algorithms in attribute value, e.g attribute starts with selector - `$(".form-control[name^='genres']")`

Full description https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/attribute-selectors/