# Unable to fetch children nodes from xml

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, find, each

I am trying to fetch children nodes from an xml and iterating it but somehow it is not working. My xml document :

```html
          <GetSalutationResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
             <GetSalutationResult xmlns:a="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Trips_Service.DataClass" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
                <a:error i:nil="true" xmlns:b="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/"/>
                <a:salutationslist>
                   <a:Salutations>
                      <a:SalutationID>Mr</a:SalutationID>
                      <a:SalutationName>Mr</a:SalutationName>
                   </a:Salutations>
                   <a:Salutations>
                      <a:SalutationID>Mrs</a:SalutationID>
                      <a:SalutationName>Mrs</a:SalutationName>
                   </a:Salutations>
                   <a:Salutations>
                      <a:SalutationID>Dr</a:SalutationID>
                      <a:SalutationName>Dr</a:SalutationName>
                   </a:Salutations>
                   <a:Salutations>
                      <a:SalutationID>Ms</a:SalutationID>
                      <a:SalutationName>Ms</a:SalutationName>
                   </a:Salutations>
                </a:salutationslist>
             </GetSalutationResult>
          </GetSalutationResponse>
```

and my javscript code im using to fetch the child nodes and iterating it.

```js
var result = xmldoc;          
          var v1 = $(result).find('GetSalutationResponse').find('GetSalutationResult');
            if ($(v1).find('error').length > 0 && $(v1).find('error').attr('i:nil') != 'true') {
                resp.error = new Error();
                resp.error.ErrorMessage = $(v1).find('error').find('ErrorMessage').text();
            }
            else {
                resp.salutationslist = new Array();
                $(v1).find('salutationslist').find('Salutations').each(function () {
                    var o1 = new Salutations();
                    o1.SalutationID = $(this).find('SalutationID').text();
                    o1.SalutationName = $(this).find('SalutationName').text();
                    resp.salutationslist[resp.salutationslist.length] = o1;
                });
            }
```

I debugged the code and found that its not entering inside jquery each.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `"a"` within selector and escape `":"`, see also [Why can't jQuery 3 identify the '#' character in an attribute selector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38415960/why-cant-jquery-3-identify-the-character-in-an-attribute-selector/)

```
var v1 = $(result).find('GetSalutationResponse').find('GetSalutationResult');
if ($(v1).find('a\\:error').length > 0 && $(v1).find('a\\:error').attr('i:nil') != 'true') {
  resp.error = new Error();
  resp.error.ErrorMessage = $(v1).find('a\\:error').find('ErrorMessage').text();
} else {
  resp.salutationslist = new Array();
  $(v1).find('salutationslist').find('a:\\Salutations').each(function() {
    var o1 = new Salutations();
    o1.SalutationID = $(this).find('a:\\SalutationID').text();
    o1.SalutationName = $(this).find('a:\\SalutationName').text();
    resp.salutationslist[resp.salutationslist.length] = o1;
  });
}
```

```js
var xmldoc = `<GetSalutationResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
  <GetSalutationResult xmlns:a="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Trips_Service.DataClass" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <a:error i:nil="true" xmlns:b="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/" />
    <a:salutationslist>
      <a:Salutations>
        <a:SalutationID>Mr</a:SalutationID>
        <a:SalutationName>Mr</a:SalutationName>
      </a:Salutations>
      <a:Salutations>
        <a:SalutationID>Mrs</a:SalutationID>
        <a:SalutationName>Mrs</a:SalutationName>
      </a:Salutations>
      <a:Salutations>
        <a:SalutationID>Dr</a:SalutationID>
        <a:SalutationName>Dr</a:SalutationName>
      </a:Salutations>
      <a:Salutations>
        <a:SalutationID>Ms</a:SalutationID>
        <a:SalutationName>Ms</a:SalutationName>
      </a:Salutations>
    </a:salutationslist>
  </GetSalutationResult>
</GetSalutationResponse>`;

var result = xmldoc;

console.log($(result).find("a\\:salutationslist"));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
```

Comment: i changed the javascript code and the jquery script but its not entering jquery each

Comment: Do i need to change the xml document to string. Althought few days ago it was working.

Comment: The issue with code is  that the selectors passed to `.find()` do not match elements beginning with `<a:>` within the XML `document`. Is `xmldoc` an XML `#document`?

Comment: @VinayDahiwale The same applies. See updated post. All `.find("error")` should be `.find("a\\:error")`

Comment: yes it worked but .find("error") was working first. Also i was using the jquery v1.9.1 which was stored locally i.e in project. So ideally there should'nt be any change